# Mongoose result always empty when tring to filter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

I'am trying to fetch by the field **doctorId** which is of type objectId, however it always returns an empty array. I tested it without the filter and it works fine so I don't think it's an error envolving the model or connection:
Mocha test:

```js
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test')

chai.should()

describe('Get treatments by doctorId', () => {
    it("get two entries", async () => {
        const treatments = await repository.getByDoctorId(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("6260a98cbad424eec4818556"))
        console.log(treatments)
        treatments.should.not.be.empty
    })
})
```

And the function I'am using to fetch the data:

```js
const getByDoctorId = async (doctorId) =>{
    console.log(doctorId)
    try{
        return await Treatment.find({doctorId: doctorId})
    }catch(ex){
        return null
    }
}
```

The data I'm tring to fetch:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the image you showed, `doctorId` is **not** an `ObjectId`. It's a `string`. See the difference between it and `_id` (that's an `ObjectId`).

It apparently has the same format as an `ObjectId`, but filtering as if it were one is expected to give no results. [MongoDB's `ObjectId`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-types/#std-label-objectid) is not the same as a `string`, even if they look the same.

To have the behavior you want, simply change your repository call to something like:

```js
        const treatments = await repository.getByDoctorId("6260a98cbad424eec4818556")
```

That should do the trick.

---

Note: avoid showing information like that in images. It usually scares help away.